# Putting the elements of a string in a single cell on a csv file. (python)

Tags: python, csv

ok so i'm trying to put all the element of my string in one cell of a csv file. My code is the following:

```
import csv

col = 2

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb"))

while col <= 6:
    values = []

    for line in open("file.data"):
        elements = line.strip().split(',')
        values.append(int(elements[col]))

    col += 2
    csum = sum(values)

    f.writerow(str(csum))
```

Basically I would want to get my sums in a single cell on the excel(csv) file. What I'm getting is something like this:

4 |5 | 2| 1|

The bars delimit the cells.

Comment: That indentation doesn't look right

Comment: This code won't even run. Watch out for indentation. Also, can you show your input file and explain what you are doing with sum() and col.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`writerow()` is expecting an iterable of strings, where each item from that iterable will be put in a separate column.  For example, you might use a list of strings like `f.writerow(['foo', 'bar'])` to put `foo` in the first column and `bar` in the second column.

If you just pass a string like `f.writerow('4521')`, then you will end up with `4` in the first column, `5` in the second column, and so on.  This happens because as described above, the csv module will iterate over the argument, and when you iterate over a string you get each character separately.

To fix this, just wrap the value in a list (or tuple):

```
f.writerow([str(csum)])
```